# Why on earth do $_GET and $_POST return true when they're empty?

Tags: php, arrays, post, get, isset

http://codepad.org/3duGkQZi

I understand that if `$var = array()`, `$var` will return true because even though the array is empty, it's still a set variable.

But `$_GET` and `$_POST`are not just arrays, they are arrays generated by PHP.

Why does PHP even set these variables if there's nothing to put in them? Is there something logical behind this that I'm missing?

Comment: Because they are set.

Comment: I think you are looking for `empty()` instead, because `isset()` checks... well... whether a variable is set :)

Comment: But what is the logic behind setting these variables if PHP knows for sure they're going to be empty?

Comment: @user3650808 There is no logic. They just wanted to have a set of variables to be always available everywhere.

Comment: Aren't the superglobals magical enough? Why do you want them to be even more different from regular arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Superglobals are built-in variables that are always available in all scopes
2. $_GET is a superglobal variable

therefore, $_GET is always available. This is the decision of the language developers.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Answer (score 2):

You should check wether they are empty or not with the `empty()` function or check the amount of elements with the `count()` function.

The arrays are always set, the question is: do they contain elements?

Answer (score 1):

`$_GET` and `$_POST` both are super global variables, so these already `set` as `Array`, so you should used there `empty()` method instead of `isset()`

```
if(empty($_GET)){
    ...
    ...
}
```